# How to solve this limit and How to find the value that minimizes this function?

Tags: calculus

Considering a Bloom Filter, Fistlable, I wanna determinate the probability to have a false positive.A bloom filter is a data structure with a array of bits plus a set of hashing functions. So considering that a bloom filter is a array with m bits, with and K hash function, the probability of any one location within a bloom filter is not being set by a hash function is:
$$
1 - \frac{1}{m}
$$ 
If the bloom filter uses k hash functions, then the probability that a bit in the bit array
is not set by any of the hash functions required for inserting an item is given by this
formula.
$$
\left( 1- \frac{1}{m} \right)^{k}
$$

If n items are inserted into the bloom filter then raising this formula to n will provide
the probability that a bit within the bloom filter’s bit array is still a zero after inserting
all n items. So we have
$$
\left( 1- \frac{1}{m} \right)^{k \cdot n}
$$
So, the probability that a bit in the bloom filter is a 1 after inserting n items is:

$$
p(k) = \left(1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{k \cdot n}\right)^{k} 
$$
Considering the following approximantion:
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m} = \frac{1}{e}
$$
We obtain:

$$p(k) = \left(1 - e^{\frac{-k\cdot n}{m}} \right)^{k}$$

and finally the text book said, that this value minimizes the p(k) function:
$$
k = \frac{m}{n} \cdot \ln(2)
$$
However, I don't know how to find this value, and I don't know how to solve the limit above(the approximation). Could someone help me understand theses results????

Comment: What is the problem from which you arrived at "this result", and where is your work from starting from that problem and leading to "this result"?  You need to include the problem statement, your work, etc, else it it impossible to follow your "question post".  What is the $p(k)$ function?  You see, we want to avoid the X-Y problem, where you ask about a sub-part of a question, Y, when Y might not be a correct conclusion or result, based on X: the original problem.  So please fill in the blanks and show how you get from X to Y.

Comment: @amWhy I've edited the post as you asked to me. I avoid to give the context because I think that someone could thin that is a problem of computer science but my problem is not about the subject, but about some calculus tools that the book autor are using to achieve the results.

Comment: The limit is one of the ways of defining $e^x$, which is $e^x=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ applied to $x=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find the derivative of $p$. $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} k} p( k) =\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} k}\left( 1-e^{\frac{-k\cdotp n}{m}}\right)^{k}$$
Now I'll employ the following identity: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}(f(x)^{g(x)})=f(x)^{g(x)}\left(g'(x)\ln(f(x))+\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}g(x)\right)$$
(which I can provide a derivation of, if needed) we'll use $f(k)=1-e^{\frac{-k\cdotp n}{m}}$ and $g(k)=k$ to obtain $$p'(k)=p( k)\left(\ln\left( 1-e^{\frac{-k\cdotp n}{m}}\right) +\frac{n}{m} \cdotp \frac{ke^{-k\cdotp n/m}}{1-e^{-k\cdotp n/m}}\right)$$
For minimization, we want to find the values of $k$ such that $p'(k)=0$. Since $p'(k)$ is a product, it will have a root if $p(k)=0$ (which only occurs trivially at $k=0$) or if $$\ln\left( 1-e^{\frac{-k\cdotp n}{m}}\right) +\frac{n}{m} \cdotp \frac{ke^{-k\cdotp n/m}}{1-e^{-k\cdotp n/m}}=0.$$
Let's use a change of variable $x\equiv \frac{n}{m}k$: $$\ln\left( 1-e^{-x}\right) +\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}} =0$$
I'm not sure how you'd actually go about solving this for $x$, but we can see upon inspection that $x=\ln(2)$ is certainly a root. Using our definition of $x$, this means this equation has a root at $k=\frac{m}{n}\ln(2).$
Proving that this is indeed the **only** root of $p'(k)$ is a challenge for another day.

Comment: Very good explanation. Could you say to me what's the name of this identity or give me some reference about?:$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}(f(x)^{g(x)})=f(x)^{g(x)}(g'(x)\ln(f(x))+\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}g(x)))$$                                        I've never heard about it before. It doesn't look chain rule.

Comment: You can derive it yourself. Let $h(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$. Then $\ln(h(x))=g(x)\ln(f(x))$. Use the chain rule and product rule and rearrange for $h'(x)$ and you're done.

Comment: ok, now I got it. Thanks so much!