# Derivative of $\left(\frac{\sqrt{8|x|}\sin^2 x}{\cos x}\right)^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

I'm trying to find the derivative of $$\left(\frac{\sqrt{8|x|}\sin^2 x}{\cos x}\right)^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}$$ so I can find its local minima at the interval $[0,0.5]$ and $[0,-0.5]$. How do I differentiate something like this? Is it possible to find the derivative of each part separately and then combine them again?

Comment: Use a CAS such as Wolfram Alpha. You won't learn anything interesting by doing the derivative by hand.

Comment: If you are looking for the maximum and minimum, they are respectively at $x=-.2313662770...$ and $x=.2313662770...$

Comment: @BernardMasse how is this done mathematically?

Comment: @BernardMasse What are the corresponding y-values?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685654/how-to-solve-this-limit-and-how-to-find-the-value-that-minimizes-this-function/3687508#3687508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is:

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{8 \left| x\right| } \sin ^2(x)}{\cos (x)}\right)^{\text{erf}(x)}=2^{\frac{3 \text{erf}(x)}{2}} \left| x\right| ^{\frac{\text{erf}(x)}{2}} (\sin (x) \tan (x))^{\text{erf}(x)}$$

As Bernard Masse correctly pointed out, using a CAS is efficient here. I tried the following using Mathematica:

```
FullSimplify[D[(Sqrt[8 Abs[x]]*Sin[x]^2/Cos[x])^Erf[x], x]];
```

As a result I obtained:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}e^{-x^2} 2^{\frac{3 \text{erf}(x)}{2}-1} \left| x\right| ^{\frac{\text{erf}(x)}{2}-1}\\ \cdot(\sin (x) \tan (x))^{\text{erf}(x)} \left(\sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2} \text{erf}(x)\\ \cdot\left(\text{Abs}'(x)+2 \left| x\right|  (\tan (x)+2 \cot (x))\right)+2 \left| x\right|  (\log (8 \left| x\right| )+2 \log (\sin (x) \tan (x)))\right)$$

The plot of your original function is, where the blue curve represents the real part and the orange one the imaginary part:

[image]

And your derivative looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: So it's impossible to find the derivative with a paper and pencil?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is impossible, but there will be no value in doing so.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!

Comment: What???!! There is no value in having a machine do it for you. You absolutely should do this by hand.

Comment: Ok I really need to apologize and put this into perspective. As someone who is purely practical on the road (where things must be efficient), such one-sided thinking sometimes happens to me. This is the suffering of the purely practical. When it comes to understanding how something works and why, then of course it makes sense to do such things by hand. I take back my statement and in no way want to create resentment here.

Comment: @EldarSultanow chill! I believe John was being sarcastic!!

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarifying :-). I was overcome by a guilty conscience for a moment. I added the derivative plots as well.

Comment: So are those three lines after the text "as a result I obtained:" the whole derivative?

Comment: Correct. Its the whole big term.

Comment: One more question: What's Abs`(x)? Since I'm on a school computer and my district blocked imgur, the two plots are blocked.

Comment: @DatBoi i was not being sarcastic. If this is a math problem it should be done by hand. If this showed up in the course of a science or engineering problem then a computer program is the way to go. The difference lies in the context.

Comment: @KamalSaleh: It is the derivative of the absolute value function. You may consider it as $\text{sgn}(x)$ assuming $x$ is real, see details [here at Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Derivative%5B1%5D%5BAbs%5D%5Bx%5D) by inputting `Derivative[1][Abs][x]`.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my linked answer, to take derivatives of expressions of the form $y(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$ we write
$$\log y(x)=g(x)\log f(x)$$
Use the chain rule and the product rule,
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=g'(x)\log f(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}g(x)$$
So
$$y'(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}\left(g'(x)\log f(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}g(x)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This can help me solve for the derivative on my own.